# Typescript: Generic to specific type

Tags: typescript

I have a Generic type

```
type GenericType = {
  [key: string]: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2?: string,
    prop3?: number,
  },
};
```

I use the Generic type to help build / typecheck a new object I created.

```
const Obj1: GenericType = {
  key1: {
    prop1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prop2: "sup",
  },
};
```

It works. However, when I use the new object, vscode / typescript doesn't show the keys or props of `Obj1` without removing `GenericType` from it. I can also "extend" the type but that's code duplication.

```
Obj1.???
```

Is there way to keep the GenericType while having access to the more specific props from the new object I created from it?

---

Update 1

I expect vscode / typescript to show / validate

```
Obj1.key1.prop1
Obj1.key2.prop1
```

and error if

```
Obj1.key1.prop2
Obj1.key2.prop3
Obj1.key2.prop321
```

Comment: Is your goal to restrict the keys of `Obj1` to just `key1` and `key2` or to have `key1` and `key2` offered in the autocomplete menu but still be able to add more keys later?

Comment: @MátéSolymosi My goal is to have keyx offered. I will use it to create multiple different types of models. Then use those objects in other functions / props.

Answer (score 3):

I see the use case for this being that you want `GenericType`s to have any kind of string as a key but still want to determine exactly what those keys' values can be at the point where you declare them.

In that case you can make use of the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type to restrict the allowed keys of `Obj1` to only the keys you specify.

```
type GenericType<K extends string> = Record<K, {
  prop1: string,
  prop2?: string,
  prop3?: number,
}>
```

Then when defining `Obj1` you can specify what the allowed keys should be by setting the union of allowed keys as the first type parameter.

```
const Obj1: GenericType<"key1" | "key2"> = {
  key1: {
    prop1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prop2: "sup",
  },
};
```

TypeScript will now let you access both `key1` and `key2` with full type safety.

```
Obj1.key1
// (property) key1: {
//     prop1: string;
//     prop2?: string | undefined;
//     prop3?: number | undefined;
// }
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on OP's comment it sounds like he would rather not specify all the key names or have to check for the presence of optional fields manually.

The best way I can think of doing this while still ensuring that the object you declare matches the constraints of the `GenericType` interface is to do something like the following.

First you need this utility type:

```
type Constraint<T> = T extends Record<string, {
  prop1: string,
  prop2?: string,
  prop3?: number,
}> ? T : never
```

This will return `never` if `T` doesn't match the constraint or just `T` otherwise.

Now you declare the plain object you actually want. No type annotations.

```
const CorrectObj = {
  key1: {
    prop1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prop2: "sup",
  },
};
```

Then you assign this object literal to another variable, but declaring that the new variable has to be of type `Constraint<typeof CorrectObj>`

```
const CheckedObj: Constraint<typeof CorrectObj> = CorrectObj
```

If `CorrectObj` matches the constraint then `CheckedObj` will be a simple copy of `CorrectObj` with all fields available.

If the object literal doesn't match the constraints however you will get a type error when trying to assign CheckedBadObj to the literal:

```
const BadObj = {
  key1: {
    progfdgp1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prdfgop2: "sup",
  },
};

const CheckedBadObj: Constraint<typeof BadObj> = BadObj
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Type '{ key1: { progfdgp1: string; }; key2: { prop1: string; prdfgop2: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'never'. (2322)
```

The explanation being that `Constraint<T>` when `T` doesn't match is `never`, but you are still trying to assign a non-`never` value to `CheckedBadObj`, causing a type conflict!

This involves a bit of duplication in declaring two instances of every object literal but is the only way of

1. having TypeScript know *exactly* which fields exist on the object, including all sub-objects, while still
2. checking that the values of your "generic" types
   match your constraints

You can play around with this approach in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4EMCWDgB4AqAfFALxT5QQAewECAJklAEoQDGcq9uKq2A5gBooAbwBQUKGFRwwARgBcUXgMESpMsACYA-EpUIh66bIDMeqAgCuAWwBGEVGoC%20xHeShKEEAG6OxARzIwLCcqOzAAPJ2AFakouoA1hAgigmSkibySgBEABaYOWqSzsVQySBaSuIZGrJpOXYgEEXqmZpVUDlIVmCtJS4A3IGIKLB57Mn00TFp8MEY2HigkHAAZqGo4WxRscRk8FsRMyPBUABC6NOx8TXlKWl37XD8a-T82V0F-VClSSmdJ51T6NZo-dr0Nb8WSdbq9H5-ZzDMRBMYwCZsKaXa4xJTzXhYHC4FYQdYXK4zfbknFAA).

Comment: This is the closest to pure typescript but it has a couple of issues. Other than having to type in every key, it also offers me prop2 on key1.

Comment: This solution has a similar issue compared to the other solution. It allows properties outside of whats limited by Generic type to be included ie. `{ key1: { prop1: "hi", prop321: "what" }` . However, its better than the other solution since no extra function wrapper is needed.

Comment: Why is having extra properties a problem?

Comment: My purpose for using Typescript is reduce errors like type check errors or invalid properties. If I am able to create invalid properties (probably due to miss spelling) and receive no warning, I'll stick with plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your goal is to have `key1` and `key2` show up in the autocomplete menu for `Obj1` but still have the ability to set additional keys later, here is a possible solution:

```js
type GenericType = {
  [key: string]: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2?: string,
    prop3?: number,
  };
};

const generify = <T extends GenericType>(obj: T): T & GenericType => obj;

const Obj1 = generify({
  key1: {
    prop1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prop2: "sup",
  },
});
```

I cannot think of a simpler solution right now that would give `Obj1` the same intersection type between `GenericType` and the specific type containing only the `key1` and `key2` properties.

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for, however, this is adding an unnecessary javascript function wrapper. I'm surprised there isn't a pure typescript way to resolve this.

Comment: It also looks like I can add new props other than whats listed in the GenericType. ie `key1: { prop321: "boom" }`

Comment: That's an unfortunate side effect of this solution since `key1: { prop1: string; prop321: string; }` technically extends `key1: { prop1: string; prop2?: string; prop3?: number; }`.

Comment: I have tried to come up with an elegant solution to this but every approach was a bit hack-y in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic utility function (`enforce`) that

- ensures the object matches `GenericType` using a generic constraint (`extends`)
- and returns the type of the passed in object for type inference.

Code:

```
type GenericType = {
  [key: string]: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2?: string,
    prop3?: number,
  };
};

const enforce = <T extends GenericType>(obj: T): T => obj;
```

## Working solution:

```
type GenericType = {
  [key: string]: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2?: string,
    prop3?: number,
  };
};

const enforce = <T extends GenericType>(obj: T): T => obj;

const Obj1 = enforce({
  key1: {
    prop1: "hi",
  },
  key2: {
    prop1: "bye",
    prop2: "sup",
  },
});


Obj1.key1.prop1; // Ok
Obj1.key2.prop1; // Ok

/** 
 * ERROR: does not match passed in object
 */
Obj1.key1.prop2 // Error 
Obj1.key2.prop3 // Error
Obj1.key2.prop321 // Error

Obj1.key3; // Error 

/**
 * ERRORS: Does not match GenericType
 */
const Obj2 = enforce({
  key1: { // Error 
  }
});
const Obj3 = enforce({
  key1: {
    prop1: 123, // Error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this answer is just like Mate's answer and with the same downsides. It still allows the user to enter more properties than specified in `GenericType` and when transcribed to javascript, it adds an extra function.