# Typescript validation for properties of an object returned from a callback passed to a generic React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

This feels like so much achievable with TS, nevertheless, I couldn't.

This is my generic component interface:

```js
export interface DataTableProps<T> {
  data: {
    id: string;
    view: T;
  }[];

  cellModifications?: (
    cellData: T[keyof T],
    rowId: string,
  ) => {
    [key: string]: TableCellProps & {  // trying to find better typing here for key: string
      content?: string | number | JSX.Element;
    };
  };
}
```

This is how I use it:

```js
<DataTable<StatsFormatted>
      data={list}
      cellModifications={
        (cellData, id) => ({
          statName: {
            align: 'center',
            content: cellData,
          },
        })
      }
    />
```

So the thing is, the object returned from `cellModification` callback has to include **only** the keys that are in the `list` passed to the `data` prop. I am trying to write a TS validation for that.

What I have tried so far are:

- I converted `[key: string]` in the interface to `[key in key of T]` and that worked great, it started to validate. However, that expected *all* the fields in the `T` object. That is not useful for my case, I only want to pass down some of them.
- I also tried `[key in key of Partial<T>]`. Problem with that is that even though it checks the properties against `T` it still accepts any extra key. So still, not good.
- Then, I tried this:

```js
[key in StrictPropertyCheck<
   T,
   keyof Partial<PolicyStats['view']>,
   'bad key'
>]
```

which uses this

```js
export type StrictPropertyCheck<T, TExpected, TError> = T extends TExpected
  ? Exclude<keyof T, keyof TExpected> extends never
    ? T
    : TError
  : TExpected;
```

and this one actually did what exactly the first thing I have tried did and gave an error expecting *all* the fields in `T`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Here is a [TS Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQLABQ99BArgHb7AStwDmWMAFQCeYLABMA0liGoAPAIB8ACggAjAFYAuOAICUcAN704cSjGZRuSgPIas+AHQBraahUb9aOGyesIAd1ZPdABBKChkIVkXIQgCHQUAbnoAX0Y6LAAPSFg4YFYYLCgCPCw4ABFkGGQBZFUAGywABWIwOUVDYzgxKuRtIzoTE2AxbVQYKHyeZMGhgDdgLH9tARmTFIBtAF0ZrtwsevqAWQgxYAJgXCrOVlRtJS6TfcPK6pWNmLidLYAaR9MAgBJUZwcaTVg8P6zfQAXgUnVmQzgH2keW4n3iTWQsGAyHq8gUW36SJJpLJAHpyXBZABaOn0+lwAByEBglzKwHgwHQWJxeLgXwE-yRuC4hQKYwmUzWJJSMvWMzSDAy2Wg8FFt3grxqdUacBh1IEcCy4rE6GwoqgYlkYKmP28rF8AVYCmUBm6vXtz2Op3Ol2uXFQUJS2m1tQazVa7QUsPhAyegfgPWqUhk+o91QcjQhMAAFnB4QAGOAAfl4-GEokkriUyeQG0LWwcCyW+m02xlZgsVn+sjOcwUwsMdYcIGQYCUSndI3tLf8cBSsYRZIzyFTqFH48nMSX8ZXcA14wPB3q2vTc5RQh2Q5FibgIF9FyubMD6e9JzOT4DtyU3u19pGXR5TJQ91RPABhMUsAKdMH0-f0X1uS8mw1cUYGA0ku0sal+wUAxvUggpoJgFJZHJXCbwXXQh0XJUkTIijoVSdIYBEMowzY9N3X3HjeKRSlqQZISdFzIoOXQPw4AAIlUZAAC8pLgC4DjENE4FEyh7VQCAugICAIElcFpi6WSoEM6VmOVWQw11LBrN6SssEHWY6xhAwNn+PckRGbQyBGMgoVJOd+kovSDPIMKAso0zfNM2hESGOjEq6LYkvfR8EJuVA3N-E9-wBfxgSXKd-jCkKEoTIiJQi-SaVQ4j4qRFJAqGWS5OJPjOq6kwBNpITGQEABlUFcwgZh6jEVgyHgRp4BAMowGYeA825NSNKwId6uqsg2rqqCCjIOB-iS2j6HJZygA)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you put a minimal reproducible example in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)? It would make it much easier to help you here.

Comment: I am sure - trying to create a typescript playground example

Comment: @AlexWayne I have just added a minimal example of the problem I am having, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @RameshReddy You can see in the playground example I have just added that Partial doesn't really work.

Comment: @Ege Your playground example is incomplete.

Comment: @Ege we all are waiting for working example :D

Comment: Hey guys, I am sorry, I don't know what happened but the link goes to some incomplete TS Playground, I have updated the link. Please try again. And thank you so much. @captain-yossarian

Comment: Just updated it, link was broken @SILENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of a feature called [Excess Property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). There are some tricks to overcome it but they are unreliable - [Is it possible to restrict typescript object to contain only properties defined by its class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580725/is-it-possible-to-restrict-typescript-object-to-contain-only-properties-defined)

---

Explanation

Excess property checks will make the object either require all existing props + any props or any props. Due to Excess Property checks, there is no option in between (ie only allow specified props). This annoying feature has been made for TypeScript to fit JavaScript. I had asked a similar problem - [Typescript: variable of type doesn't type check under certain circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682397/typescript-variable-of-type-doesnt-type-check-under-certain-circumstances)

Comment: In my third try I explained above, I am checking it for excess properties but the result is the same. What you are telling me is already a part of my question.

Comment: @Ege As mentioned, its a feature that isn't reliably overridden. It will either require all existing props + any props or any props. Due to Excess Property checks, there is no in between option (ie only allow specified props). These annoying feature has been made for TypeScript to fit JavaScript. I had asked a similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682397/typescript-variable-of-type-doesnt-type-check-under-certain-circumstances

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This comment explains more about the issue comparing to your real answer since your question about this issue in the other StackOverflow thread points to the fact that excess property check is not possible when used in combination with generics.